# Como almaceno enteros desde un while en un array?

Tags: java

Como hago para que se almacenen en el array "arrayPrimos" de forma automatica los números que va generando mi while? La idea es almacenar los 15 primeros números primos y despues recorrer el array mostrando por pantalla el resultado, lo cual sí se hacer.

```
package array;

import bucleFor.Mates;

public class ForArrays1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int número = 2;
        int contador = 0;
        int [] arrayPrimos = new int [14];
        
        System.out.println("Los 15 primeros números primos son: ");
        while (contador <15) {
            if (Mates.esPrimo(número)) {
                contador++;
                //entiendo que aquí es donde tengo q almacenar los datos en el array
                }
            número++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Estos son los 15 primeros números primos mostrados desde un array");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayPrimos.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayPrimos[i]);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: `arrayPrimos[contador] = blablabla;`. Imagino que esto es una duda de clase... y no es por mal, pero a tu profesor le pagan por enseñarte! Lo normal es que intentes hacerlo, revises los apuntes, otros ejercicios que hayas hecho, y si tienes dudas aun así, preguntes al profesor. Su trabajo es explicarte todo para que lo entiendas. Aquí podemos ayudar con algún error concreto, pero no vamos a ponernos a explicarte la teoría y sinceramente, copiar y pegar lo que te digamos no va a *enseñarte* nada útil. Aprender a hacer CPP (copy paste programming) no es una habilidad útil en el mundo real :)

Comment: Por cierto, intuyo que tu código es copiado y pegado porque te he visto acceder al array en el system.out, y asignarlo es exactamente lo mismo... si sabes acceder a él, deberías saber acceder a él sea para leerlo o para asignarlo. Como he dicho... copiar y pegar sin *entender*, no sirve absolutamente de nada. Si tienes dudas, antes que copiar y pegar, pide que te lo expliquen. O llegará el punto que irás tan a rastras que te vas a bloquear y vas a ver que "reaprender" la base es más complicado cuando tienes mil cosas que aprender, en vez de haber ido pasito a pasito desde el principio.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta en cuanto a enseñarme como rellenarlo, pero te equivocas, el código esta integramente hecho por mi. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int número = 2;
int contador = 0;
int [] arrayPrimos = new int [14];

System.out.println("Los 15 primeros números primos son: ");
while (contador <15) {
    if (Mates.esPrimo(número)) {
        arrayPrimos[contador] = número;
        contador++;
        }
    número++;
}

System.out.println("Estos son los 15 primeros números primos mostrados desde un array");
for (int i = 0; i < arrayPrimos.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayPrimos[i]);
}
```

}

Desconozco si se pueden usar acentos en variables.

Comment: Jamás uses acentos en variables. Da igual el lenguaje, no lo hagas. Una cosa es que se pueda y otra muy diferente que se deba.

Comment: Piensa que una i y una í se diferencian bien poco en pantalla. Imagina la de problemas si en una parte escribes con acento y en otra sin, y si ambas variables existen.

Comment: ¿Crees que el OP entienda tu respuesta asi, sin ninguna explicación? ¿En qué falló o qué le falto al OP para completar su ejercicio? ¿Que habilidades debe fortaceler? Un puro código sin explicación tal vez le sirva al OP, pero a nadie más.